# New Form not saving values but saving item as empty

Tags: list, form, newform

I have a simple item list. We have a form that's customized by simply adding Headers to seperate different sections. It was working fine but suddently when we fill out the form and save an item all the fields are empty and the title returns (no title).

There was no change to the form before this occured. If we create a new add form that form creates items without issue, I just don't want to reformat this new form if I don't have too.

Any ideas why the old form might just stop saving properties?

Comment: Is it a custom form? Do you have any workflows or event receivers?

Comment: No workflows or event receivers. It's just a list form with a few html elements added in for styling